# Can i get the list of associated keywords to a specific file,

Tags: google-drive-api

i.e. for an image that OCR is performed, i want to be able to fetch the list of text on the image. Is this possible using the SDK? If so how, and if  not are there any suggestions as to using google's OCR to fetch words in an image.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

When you [create](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert) a file or [copy](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/copy) it with the Drive API, you can perform OCR on it to convert it to a Google Document which will contain the OCR text. The relevant parameters are:

- `ocr`            *boolean*    Whether to attempt OCR on .jpg, .png, or .gif uploads.
- `ocrLanguage`    *string*     If ocr is true, hints at the language to use. Valid values are ISO 639-1 codes.

Comment: This answer seems incomplete; I see from the SDK docs that I can upload a file and have it ocr'd on Drive, but I don't see any property of the file response that contains the resulting text. Is there another step (i.e. query the GDoc created in the OCR request - but that's not text?) or am I not seeing the correct property in file response?

Comment: For what Ali described, it requires setting covert=true in the query parameters when uploading the file. That will create a doc with the image and extracted text. There is no way to extract the text for unconverted images.

Comment: @SteveBazyl I think you meant "There is no way to extract the text from CONVERTED images"

Comment: @Franklin No, I meant exactly what I said. An image that is converted into a Google doc with OCR will have any extracted text in the document. That text can then be extracted by converting the document back to text or any other readable format. OCR is still performed on unconverted images for purposes of search indexing but the extracted text is not exposed in the API.

FWIW - The OCR feature in Drive isn't meant to be used for programatic extraction of text from images. It's possible via conversions as mentioned, but definitely not the intended use case.

Comment: @SteveBazyl Thanks for the clarification. After conversion, it is true the text is available in the document but so is the image. I am not sure if we can get back the text alone.